# Pandas: How to add yearly average to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
year  x             y
1987  1.609438      0
1988  1.386294      0
1989  1.098612      1
1987  0.693147      0
1988  0.000000      0
1989 -0.693147      1
```

...

So, I can get the average of x by year doing

```
>>> df.groupby(['year'])['x','y'].mean()
   x     y
year     meanX     meanY                    
1987     0.597434  0.000000
1988     0.428441  0.351852
1989     0.155169  0.185185
```

How can I add a new column associating each row to the year? I mean I want something like this:

```
year  x             y   meanX   meanY
1987  1.609438      0   0.597434  0.000000
1988  1.386294      0   0.428441  0.351852
1989  1.098612      1   0.155169  0.185185
1987  0.693147      0   0.597434  0.000000
1988  0.000000      0   0.428441  0.351852
1989 -0.693147      1   0.155169  0.185185
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand how you got that output for 'meanY' but are you after `In [196]:

df
df[['meanx','meany']] = df.groupby('year')[['x','y']].transform('mean')
df
Out[196]:
   year         x  y     meanx  meany
0  1987  1.609438  0  1.151293      0
1  1988  1.386294  0  0.693147      0
2  1989  1.098612  1  0.202733      1
3  1987  0.693147  0  1.151293      0
4  1988  0.000000  0  0.693147      0
5  1989 -0.693147  1  0.202733      1`?

Comment: I mean I presented only part of the database. Note the "...". Is this your question? Sorry! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
df['x_mean'] = df.groupby('year').x.transform(lambda s: s.mean())
df['y_mean'] = df.groupby('year').y.transform(lambda s: s.mean())

>>> df
   year         x  y    x_mean  y_mean
0  1987  1.609438  0  1.151293       0
1  1988  1.386294  0  0.693147       0
2  1989  1.098612  1  0.202733       1
3  1987  0.693147  0  1.151293       0
4  1988  0.000000  0  0.693147       0
5  1989 -0.693147  1  0.202733       1
```

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.DataFrame.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) should do what you want:

```
data =  [
  {'year': 1987, 'x': 1.5116, 'y': 0},
  {'year': 1988, 'x': 1.135, 'y': 1}
]
means = df.groupby(['year'])['x', 'y'].mean()
df.merge(right=means, left_on='year', right_index=True, suffixes=('', 'mean'))
```

Returns:

```
        x  y  year   xmean  ymean
0  1.5116  0  1987  1.5116      0
1  1.1350  1  1988  1.1350      1
```