# Printing the same values from a list without duplicates

Tags: python

I have a text file looking something like this, but much bigger (spans from 1993 - 2013)

```
2001:3.342
2001:2.345
2001:2.211
2001:4.31
2002:3.23
2002:2.231
2002:2.12
2003:1.23
2003:2.32
2003:2.12
```

On the left we have years and on the right their sales. What I'm trying to do is take each year and find the average mean of that year. I know what I've done with my code is the long route, so I'm just wondering if there is a quicker way for the future.

What I've done:

```
for line in year_value:
    x, y = line.split(":")
    if x == "2001":
        value.append(float(y))
        avg_value01 = sum(value) / len(value)
    print("The average sales in 2001 were : ", avg_value01)
```

I had to do this for 20 different years

I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to do this rather using vanilla Python, as I'm only a beginner and want to get used to the basics.

Comment: Seems like a pretty straight forward task if you look into `pandas` for example. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801003/pandas-how-to-add-yearly-average-to-dataframe)

Comment: `if x == x:` will always  be `True`.

Comment: Apologies my example should have been x == "2001". I have corrected that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the condition `x == x` will always be True as you don't progress to the next line `n+1`, say, while you are still on `n`.

One approach would be to convert these pairings to a dictionary, where the key will the year and its value will be a list of the values corresponding to that year.

```
year_value_dict = {}
for line in year_value:
    year, value = line.split(':')
    year_values_dict.setdefault(year, []).append(value)

for year, values in year_values_dict.items():
    print(f"The average sales in {year} was : {sum(values)/len(values)}"
```

The `setdefault` method returns the value for the key provided in the first argument (`year`); if not it creates the key and sets the second argument (an empty list) as a value. In any case, you will have a list to which you can append `value`.

In the second loop, you iterate through each key-value pair at print the values.

NOTE:

- If you are using Python < 3.6, the dictionary keys may not be ordered. Otherwise they are ordered in which the way they were inserted.
- I use f-strings in the second loop, which are also only available in Python >= 3.6. You can format in the old fashion, if you want.

Comment: Thank you! Greatly appreicated!

Answer (score 1):

The below should work for you (use a dict to hold the data for each year)

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
with open('test.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    year,value = line.split(':')
    data[year].append(float(value))
for year,sales in data.items():
  print(f'{year} -> {sum(sales) / len(sales)}')
```

test.txt

```
2001:3.342
2001:2.345
2001:2.211
2001:4.31
2002:3.23
2002:2.231
2002:2.12
2003:1.23
2003:2.32
2003:2.12
```

output

```
2001 -> 3.0519999999999996
2002 -> 2.527
2003 -> 1.89
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been meaning to try this for a while, writing a `Mean` aggregator class.

Copying balderman's solution, but keeping track of means with constant space each, instead of lists with linear space each. With a convenient `mean()` method, making the "main" code cleaner.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Mean:
    def __init__(self):
        self._sum = 0
        self._size = 0
    def add(self, value):
        self._sum += value
        self._size += 1
    def mean(self):
        return self._sum / self._size

data = defaultdict(Mean)
with open('test.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    year,value = line.split(':')
    data[year].add(float(value))
for year,sales in data.items():
  print(f'{year} -> {sales.mean()}')
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJBbsMgELzzir2B1ZTGuJUqS@kP@oKqspCNFSQMFqybplHe7gKu0ygKp/HO7uwMeDzi3tnqdfTzfNC4BzcqyyiqgBy/kW6AHmgBMkBfE4in5wevUTFKqdhuy7ri1bMgGYoIX1YoynKBz7zKSMRWUS0o0mtR8DKPV3X5R1dJSKwosnFVQUjv3QCtM0a1qJ0NoIfReYRO9XIy2OkWCWmNDAHelbSL20hC02irsWlYUKYvlno66ZM3YRpgB9vbqv5Rl3ISkV2X5zfwJc2k7so87BbynlbkyovYEP3duvEKJ2@v1J6uxgnpJMpo6CosSykLcu/R/t@rdx6Mtgq0XR/wqKTfZJ9RL3E8jEYjo3W85ewwrvpIXZ88pe6Nk8iW1AVJglkhSKNCkk3tPP4RQ2A5zui1RdbTU2o7w@MbnHIvz6mLc9wyz78)):

```
2001 -> 3.0519999999999996
2002 -> 2.527
2003 -> 1.89
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the lines of the file and create a dictionary that had the all the values for each year associated with a list of the value encountered for it. Once you have that it is each to calculate the mean value of what's in each list using the `fmean()` function in the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module.

```
text = '''\
2001:3.342
2001:2.345
2001:2.211
2001:4.31
2002:3.23
2002:2.231
2002:2.12
2003:1.23
2003:2.32
2003:2.12
'''

from statistics import fmean

yearly = {}
for line in text.splitlines():
    pair1, pair2 = zip([int, float],line.split(':'))
    year, value = pair1[0](pair1[1]), pair2[0](pair2[1])
    yearly.setdefault(year, []).append(value)

for year, data in yearly.items():
    avg = fmean(data)
    print(f'The average sales in {year} were {avg:.3f}')
```